# MS Graph API: Using a contains operator in query

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

How do I do a contains string in a graph api request?

I want to find all emails with the a subject that contains the key word 'orange' from a particular user. Something like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jane.doe@example.com/messages?$search="to:jane.doe@example.com and contains(Subject, 'orange')"&$select=subject,from,toRecipients,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview
```

Where can i find all the graph api operators and filters. I've taken a look at: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
but only see very simple examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran some tests. Search looks like it works like it would in Outlook. Just use `key:'value'` pairs with spaces inside `$search`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/jane.doe@example.com/messages?$search="to:jane.doe@example.com Subject:'orange'"&$select=subject,from,toRecipients,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview
```

Comment: the `to:` was breaking it for me. had to use `toRecipients`

Comment: that lines up with the rest of the URL :)